# Synchronous execution of methods in windows service

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a windows service to execute some method every x minutes, but I want the method to execute synchronously relative to the timer itself. The windows service have a Timer object (System.Timers.Timer) which starts and calls some method 'DoWork' every x minutes, but the timer must 'stop' while 'DoWork' is executing and starts again after the method is finished.

I'm aware that using the System.Windows.Forms.Timer class would give me the behavior I want, but I don't want to add a System.Windows.Forms dll reference to my Service project.

Here is an example of 'working' code:

```
    private System.Timers.Timer timer1;

    public void MainMethod()
    {
        timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
        timer1.Start();
    }

    void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        DoWork();
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("found!");
    }
```

Running above in a console application (as a mockup before writing the windows service), the expected behavior should be for the console to write 'found!' every 3 seconds.

Just a side-note: I'm just using 'Thread.Sleep(2000)' to mimic a delay but it won't form part of the actual code base.

Is there any other / "better" way to achieve this than my way above?

Thanks for reading my question and any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set your interval to 3000 instead of 1000. Then you won't need the delay in the DoWork method.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I literally just used that extra 2 seconds to mimic an action that could take a while (like calling some service method or executing a complicated stored proc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `System.Forms.Timer` in a windows service because that would require a message pump and Windows services are not given a message pump stack that can be very large (plus you'd have to call `Application.Run` to start one).

The way you have it now is the way I implement periodic events.  I'd add something to monitor whether your events take longer than the period; but other than that...

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks so much for replying :) seems like this is the best way to go about (per the requirements) .. the whole idea to 'stop' the timer in the Elapsed event and then start it again afterwards made me a bit uneasy and I thought there might be some property or method on the timer itself that I could use instead. I read that the 'SynchronizingObject' property is set when using the System.Windows.Forms.Timer but not when using the System.Timers.Timer and that's why the one executes asynchronously and the other synchronously (in a nutshell) ?

Comment: You want to use Stop because you don't want don't want to be processing two `Elapsed` events at the same time.  You *can* if you write code to support that; but if you don't write that code you should use Stop/Start.  Yes, Windows.Forms.Timer works with a message queue so only one Tick (or any single message) can be processed at a time.

Comment: can't agree with you more: "You can if you write code to support that; but if you don't write that code you should use Stop/Start." .. I did make another mockup using backgroundworker that achieved the same functionality but didn't stick to the requirement of synchronous. Am calling it a day now, on my way home - will mark your reply tomorrow as the answer! Thanks a lot, man. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on whether you just want the X second delay between calls to the method to be a constant, or if you'd like the method to be called every X seconds, but with allowances if the method takes longer than X seconds to execute.

Your code above will do the former, where there's a one second delay between method calls, but if you want your method to be called every X seconds, you may want to consider using timestamps with `DateTime.Now` and `DateTime.Subtract` to see if a suitable time has passed since the last method call.  This may cause unusual behaviour if the system clock gets changed, such as at daylight saving time where the method may not run for an hour but this unusual behaviour may be deemed acceptable to you in your situation.

Comment: Hi MCattle, thanks for helping out .. the idea is just to make sure that I won't process two 'Elapsed' events at the same time. The exact interval between the executions don't need to be fixed tho, otherwise I'd have to do exactly what you suggested :)

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the main problem you are having is described as " the timer must 'stop' while 'DoWork' is executing and starts again after the method is finished" .In short, the service needs to be multi-threaded. You should consider using a thread pool. Using a thread pool will allow your executing thread to continue counting time will a background thread does some other work. Check out the ThreadPool docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=vs.80%29.aspx .

Comment: He's detailed that he wants "synchronous".  If he introduces multi-threading that becomes "asynchronous"--which introduces synchronization, etc.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for helping out and also adding to the answer :) The idea is for the same kind of behavior as when running a timer on a windows forms: everything literally 'stops' while the code inside the method executes. Similarly, I want the 'DoWork' to stop everything else (including the timer) until it is done before starting the timer again. I even considered using the backgroundworker class to kick off the code inside a seperate thread, and it can also work, but sticking to the requirement (to have it executed synchronously) my idea didn't quite hit the spot.